# Detecting which backlink was clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, hyperlink, google-analytics

I have a website and I want to find out the exact place where the user clicked a link to get to my website. Is there any way to do this? I want to use this data within my code as input to a traffic analysis script.

Sorry, if this is too noobish.

TIA

Comment: More information on framework / environment would help us formulate a precise answer.

Comment: I'm using a reverse nginx proxied nodejs server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the built-in http module

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var referrer = request.headers.referer
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @beanie, will check this out and mark answered accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

you can get the referer from Rails through `request.referer`

Comment: Sorry, no Rails.. Any options for node?

Comment: if you use the built-in http server from node, than its possible to get the referrer with request.headers.referer